# Smaller strings from pickle.dumps

Tags: python-3.x, compression, pickle

I'm trying to figure out a way to make pickle strings smaller. The pickle string will reside in the script and can't be a file.

The example below is a small dictionary of which I won't know the contents. Notice how much of the string is just \x. The string I'm trying to compress is 93,878  characters long. A limitation I have is that it needs to use vanilla python libraries. I've tried using gzip then getting the string from that. It saves about 2k characters. It would be nice to save a lot more.

Any suggestions for making the string size smaller out of pickle or similar vanilla python packages would be great. 
(In the example, there are less characters than pickled string, but generally this is not the case.)

```
#Example precomputed data dict.
x = {}
x["T1"] = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5]])
x["T2"] = np.array([[3,4,5,6,7]])
pickle.dumps(x)

# Below is what will end up being used in a script. I would like to use less characters.
pickle_string = b'\x80\x03}q\x00(X\x02\x00\x00\x00T1q\x01cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\nq\x02cnumpy\nndarray\nq\x03K\x00\x85q\x04C\x01bq\x05\x87q\x06Rq\x07(K\x01K\x01K\x05\x86q\x08cnumpy\ndtype\nq\tX\x02\x00\x00\x00i4q\nK\x00K\x01\x87q\x0bRq\x0c(K\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00<q\rNNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00tq\x0eb\x89C\x14\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00q\x0ftq\x10bX\x02\x00\x00\x00T2q\x11h\x02h\x03K\x00\x85q\x12h\x05\x87q\x13Rq\x14(K\x01K\x01K\x05\x86q\x15h\x0c\x89C\x14\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00q\x16tq\x17bu.'

precomputed_data = pickle.loads(pickle_string)
```

Continuing on an idea from kabanus.

```
import zlib
s = str(zlib.compress(pickle.dumps(parameters)))
s = s.replace("X", "XX") #searched for XX in the string to begin with. 
s = s.replace("\\x", "X")
```

The reduces the character count down from 93878 to 72688.

Comment: That's because `\x` denotes the start of a hex code and delineates where each code should be. I think it's a bad idea to be playing around with pickle output as a string. Why do you need pickle anyway? Why not just dump the raw data (and zip it if you really need to)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cheap solution is to give up some pickle data and use Numpy's `tobytes` feature. On my machine:

```
>>> y = {k: v.tobytes() for k, v in x.items()}
>>> len(pickle.dumps(x))
298
>>> len(pickle.dumps(y))
114
```

The cost of course is you do not keep the `dtype` here, but saving `"int"` in your pickle is still much cheaper, especially if you have the same type for all arrays.

You can then do much better with `zlib`:

```
>>> import zlib
>>> len(zlib.compress(pickle.dumps(y))
59
```

Compressing `x` goes down only to 207, so much less optimal.

Comment: I gave this a try. However it only saved 1k characters. 93878 vs 92869. Using zlib I get a small reduction down to 92572 characters in the string. The numbers in the dictionary are floats.

Comment: I liked your idea and added some more character removal. I edited my question with a code example.